# How do I delete certain patterns in a string?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, substring

I'm trying to turn a returned string into an array with certain characters taken out so I can add it into a vertical list.

**Input**:
"\n\n1. Separate clothes into whites, lights and darks.\n2. Fill washing machine with cold water and select the appropriate cycle for the type of clothing.\n3. Add the appropriate laundry detergent, fabric softener and other laundry additives.\n4. Place clothes in the washing machine and press start."

**Note that in the first one it has two linebreaks with a number (\n\n1.) and in the rest it only has one line break with a number (\n2.)**

My end goal is to have some type of regex, or replace occurences for every numbered step to delete. I want it to return as ["Separate clothes into whites, lights and darks.", "Fill washing machine with cold water and select the appropriate cycle for the type of clothing.", etc etc] then to put it in a list. My problem is my regex or syntax isn't working, the one I use is "\n([+-]?(?=.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:.?\d*))(?:eE)? "

I've gotten it to work perfectly in Python but am new to swift so please have mercy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `split` to divide the text into an array. Unfortunately I couldn't get it tot work with only using `split` so I first used `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options)` to modify the values to split on

```
let rows = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\\d\\. ", with: "\n", options: [.regularExpression])
    .split(separator: "\n")
```

Maybe someone can make the regex work directly in `split`